# How can we send BOOL in place of (JSON or Data) in httpBody in swift, Inshort I want to send true in place of {value : true}?

Tags: swift

Body should contain only bool not json object or data.

I have tried converting bool to type in `JSON`.

```
request.httpMethod = "PUT"
        let session = URLSession(configuration:URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)     

  var value: Bool? = false

    if let _ = value
    {

        let data = Data(bytes: &value, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: value)) //Int 

        var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpBody = data
}
```

> Parsed JSON: 'Optional({"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad
>   Request","message":"value must be a
>   boolean","validation":{"source":"payload","keys":["value"]}})'

Comment: In practice `httpBody` must be Data. The question is what Data representation of a Bool is expected? Numeric 1/0, String "1"/"0", String "true"/"false" or ... ? In terms of Data a Bool is a virtual value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a simple struct:

```
struct RequestData: Encodable {
let value: Bool
}
```

and parse it using JSON:

```
let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(RequestData(value: true))
```

use it simply:

```
request.httpBody = data
```

**EDITED**

for simple bool use this:

```
let data = "true".data(using: .ascii)
```

this is a valid json

Comment: it is still showing Parsed JSON: 'Optional({"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"value must be a boolean","validation":{"source":"payload","keys":["value"]}})' I think api is accepting true boolean rather than {true} json object.